Spam Registrations Bypassing WordPress Registration
I have a custom platform built that requires users to register with more information than is required by the standard WordPress registration process.
I also have custom front-end login and password resets as well as a custom registration form.  The form requires Waiver acceptance, and I use different honeypots (that aren't labelled anything like honeypot) that, if filled out, will terminate the creation of a new user via PHP.
I use JS Validation to make sure that phone numbers are actual phone numbers and that postal codes are valid Canadian postal codes.
And, when creating the account IF things like first name, last name, Year of Birth, Month of Birth, Day of Birth, Address, etc. are blank, then I terminate the user creation on the server side (PHP) and simply do NOT create the account.
Somehow though, starting yesterday, I'm suddenly getting bot accounts created on my site. One every 30 minutes and what boggles my mind is that these accounts have NONE of the standard user data that is required by my registration form.
They don't have first or last names, none of the data for birth dates, none of the address data, none of the waiver data... ...which leads me to believe that these bots are bypassing the registration process I have customized and which I redirect my registration to happen through.
If I manually add /wp-login.php?action=register to my site's URL, it redirects to my custom login - and that custom login form won't create an account that has empty $_POST['custom_user_meta_field'] for the assorted registration fields I require.
The site uses very few plugins... ...User Switcher, so we can test new features we add for users, Comment Subscriptions, Yoast, ManageWP Worker and TinyPNG image optimization.
The theme is also 100% custom.
So, the question I need answered is:  Does anyone know of any other paths that could be utilized to register accounts in WP other than wp-login.php?action=register?
UPDATE:
So, I have identified the method being used:
curl -L "https://domain.tld/wp-login.php?action=register" -X POST -d "user_login=test1234&user_email=user@domain.tld"
Running that through something like Postman will create a new user... ...now, I am redirecting users that hit wp-login.php?action=register however, it appears that this direct method grants access BEFORE the redirect fires in my plugin (on init) because it fully avoids all of the conditions and requirements I have added in.
So, how do I get my redirect to run earlier OR how do I manually add a requirement for another value when someone directly tries to create an account using the method above?  For example, if I made ALL WP registrations require a First Name and Last Name and hooked that into the default method, bots wouldn't know and the attempt would fail.

Is there any info in your log files that might help? Accesses to the site (or POST submissions) at about the time the new users are being created?

The only complaint I have against my host provider is that you have to log into the dashboard and click a link and then wait for an email with a link to downloadable log files. It's quite annoying.  I've been away the past few days so haven't really had a chance to check them - just waiting for the email now.

Looking at the logs, which took forever to get an email for... ...the only access points I see in there is wp-login.php... ...I'm going to have to revisit the processing function that creates the account, see if I can tighten it up and why blank values are still getting through.
